# STM32F3 Can't get the UART to work in this particular case

Tags: arm, stm32, microcontroller, stm32cubeide, stm32f3

I am having trouble making a very simple transmission between two STM32F3 Discovery boards. Let me explain what I'm doing.

I have Board-A connected via i2c to an LCD 20x4 and Board-B connected via i2c to a Qrobot 3D Gesture Sensor, the goal is to catch the movement from Board-B, blink some leds on the same board and send a number via UART (uart4) to the BoardA.

The problem is that although the debug shows that the transmission takes place, actually the Board-A  never enters in the callback of RxCpltCallback. Before dive into the topic with more details, lets me show you the code:

This is the Receive callback of the Board-A. (Also this probram was tested receiving via Uart4 from another F3 (that F3 was sending also via uart4 but in the callback of the BushButton))

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef * huart)
{

switch (recvbuff)
    {

        case 1:
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_9);
            lcd_send_string(up);
            for(int i=0;i<5000000;i++){
                count1=count+1;
            }
            count1=0;

            lcd_send_cmd (0x01);

        break; //causa l'uscita immediata dallo switch
        case 2:
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_10);
            lcd_send_string(down);
            for(int i=0;i<5000000;i++){
                count1=count+1;
            }
            count1=0;

            lcd_send_cmd (0x01);


        break;
        case 3:
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_11);
            lcd_send_string(left);
            for(int i=0;i<5000000;i++){
                count1=count+1;
            }
            count1=0;

            lcd_send_cmd (0x01);


        break;
        case 4:
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_12);
            lcd_send_string(right);
            for(int i=0;i<5000000;i++){
                count1=count+1;
            }
            count1=0;

            lcd_send_cmd (0x01);



        break;
        case 5:
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_13);
            lcd_send_string(forward);
            for(int i=0;i<5000000;i++){
                count1=count+1;
            }
            count1=0;

            lcd_send_cmd (0x01);



        break;
        case 6:HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_14);
            lcd_send_string(backward);
            for(int i=0;i<5000000;i++){
                count1=count+1;
            }
            count1=0;

            lcd_send_cmd (0x01);



        break;
        case 7:
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_15);
            lcd_send_string(clockwise);
            for(int i=0;i<5000000;i++){
                count1=count+1;
            }
            count1=0;

            lcd_send_cmd (0x01);



        break;
        case 8:
            lcd_send_string(anticlockwise);
            for(int i=0;i<5000000;i++){
                count1=count+1;
            }
            count1=0;

            lcd_send_cmd (0x01);



        break;
        case 9:
            lcd_send_string(wave);
            for(int i=0;i<5000000;i++){
                count1=count+1;
            }
            count1=0;

            lcd_send_cmd (0x01);



        break;
        default:

        break;
    }
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart4, (uint8_t*)&recvbuff, sizeof(uint32_t));

}
```

This seems to work properly, I don't think the problem is here.

Let's look the code of Board-B: this program have to check, in a loop, some flags that stands for the gesture, when one occurs blink some leds and send via huart a number, a really simple task!

```
   while (1)
   {
         /* USER CODE END WHILE */
         Gesture_Data = DEV_I2C_ReadWord(PAJ_INT_FLAG1);
            if (Gesture_Data)
            {
            switch (Gesture_Data)
            {
                case PAJ_UP:                         { send(1);
                                                       HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_9);                    
                                                      break;}
                case PAJ_DOWN:                       { send(2);
                                                       HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_13);                                       
                                                       break;}
                case PAJ_LEFT:                       { send(3);
                                                       HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_15);                       
                                                       break;}
                case PAJ_RIGHT:                      { send(4);                                                       
                                                       break;}

                /* other cases */
                default: break;
            }
            Gesture_Data=0;
            DEV_Delay_ms(50);
        }
```

}

In order to test via debugging and brekpoint I have created a separated function only for the trasmit (Also tried the HAL_UART_Transimit(&huart4, (uint8_t *)num, sizeof (uint32_t), HAL_MAX_DELAY)):

```
void send(uint32_t num)
{
HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart4, (uint8_t *)num, sizeof (uint32_t));
}
```

When I try this code on the board, the sensore recognize the gesture and blink the correct led, in the debugging I can see crearly that I enter in the function sed() of the trasmit but nothing arrive on the other Board.
P.S: every cable connecting the two boards work fine and are on the correct Pins.

What do you think of it? I can't get my mind off this problem!

Comment: Tte callback breaks all rules. This callback has to be as small and fast as possible. Delays and communication functions must not be there. The problem is most likely there.

Comment: Yes I know It's not the best callback but don't know how can change it, how can i print 9 things depending on wath I receive. However, the Board-A program with this callback seems to work, I tested it by connecting it to a Board-C with a program that sent a different number to each PushButton Callback and the Board-A correctly printed the various messages on the display. How I can change things to try to get it done?

Comment: First prove the transmitter is working.  You could do this by connecting the transmitter to a PC to see if a terminal application can receive the transmission.  Or look at the UART signals with a logic analyzer or oscilloscope.  Then for the receiver you're probably going to have to dig into the HAL code to see what if anything is happening at that lower layer.